# Novel where a young man uses folding magic, and releases an ancient prisoner

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

Full length novel, post-2010, less than 2018.

Coming of age tale about a young man who was raised in a backwater or rural province and taught sorcery. Since he was in a remote location, the person teaching him magic couldn't teach him much; a lot of the training was based around a specific type of magic - a sort of "folding" or compressing objects - and the hero had a great talent for this power.

He travels to the capital with hopes of training at the sorcerer's academy. He manages to get into the entrance exams, but since he didn't have a broad magical education, he struggles with most of the tests ... until he comes to a test where he realises he can use his folding magic.

My memory is a little hazy here, but I think there was something like a suppression field in the test chamber and the magic is not supposed to work. He strains with all his focus and pushes through the barrier, overcoming the suppression field and shocking the examiners.

Elsewhere in the city or academy is a secret prison where an ancient sorcerer is kept under a similar suppression field. Possibly a political prisoner of some kind, having fallen out of favour. The hero is manipulated into going to the prison and using his magic which frees the captive.

Does this ring any bells with anyone?

Comment: Thanks for confirming that; I've edited your question accordingly. One other question though: is the type of magic used by the main character referred to as "folding magic" in the novel itself? If not, can you recall what specific term, if any, was used for it?

Comment: @LogicDictates Not sure. Fairly certain the main character thinks of it as folding. Whether it has a different official name, I can't recall.